# is there a way to improve performance of my multiple marker web app?

Tags: aframe, arj

This project is made using A-Frame and AR.js

Well, In the project I have like 10 different markers, and I have to know when one appears and disappears. I created the next component to do so:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("marker-controller", {
  tick: function() {
    if ( document.querySelector("#marker1").object3D && document.querySelector("#marker1").object3D.visible == true ) {
    // code when marker1 is visible
      .
      .
      .
    }else if ( document.querySelector("#markerN").object3D && document.querySelector("#markerN").object3D.visible == true ) {
    // code when markerN is visible, this is repeated 10 times

      .
      .
      .
    } else {
      // here I know that no marker is visible
    }
  }
});
```

This is very demanding for my phone and many times just crash the browser.
So I want to know if this is the best way to do it, or am I missing something?
Thanks guys.

Comment: It seems unlikely that the code you show here (times 10) would alone be crashing your browser... are there 3D models or textures also in the scene that could slow it down? One small improvement would be to store the marker elements in an array when the scene initializes, so you don't have to run `querySelector()` 20 times on each tick. If AR.js emitted events when markers were shown ([it currently does not](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/217)) that would of course be better than checking on every frame.

Comment: Right now I'm only presenting a plane with a texture for each marker. Also, the crash was because i was trying to init some audio using howler in a weird way, so I just fixed that, and now works fine.
I will try your querySelector() suggestion, and yeah, the events on markers visible, would be great. thanks for the answer.